# PHP How to get date if GMT will be a parameter?

Tags: php

How to get date if GMT will be a parameter?
Example:

```
$getGMT = "GMT 7";
$getDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo $getDateGMT = ...
```

So, when it detect GMT 7, date will be automatically show based on that GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date()` by default get time from `time()` which always return current time in seconds in UTC (no matter what is the global timezone set by `date_default_timezone_set()`

So you can easily parse `$getGMT` to get the difference time in hours, the parsing will depend on `$getGMT` format so I didn't include it in the code

```
$seconds = time() + $hourdifference *  60 * 60;
$getDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$seconds);
```